# JSXGraph: Is it possible to manually set the x and y tick distance

Tags: axis, jsxgraph, xticks

Say one draws an axis inside a given bounding box, and the ticks are automatically placed. How about placing more/fewer/different ticks along the axes? Is it possible to change the distance of x and y ticks?

**EDIT:**

I managed to control `minorTicks`, but `ticksDistance` and `ticksDelta` do not have an effect, see [MWE in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FLeupold/61Lkxb23/7/).

Comment: Yes. There are plety of options for ticks (which makes it difficult...). See https://jsxgraph.org/wiki/index.php/Ticks and http://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/Ticks.html for more information. If you have a specific example, please post it as jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your hints thus far! I added an EDIT section above with a JSFiddle link. Is there a way to get ``ticksDistance`` or ``ticksDelta`` to work such that major ticks only occur for multiples of 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already very close to the solution. The only missing attribute is `insertTicks: false`, which disables the automatic insertion of major ticks. `ticksDelta` is not necessary. Here is the code:

```
const brd0 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('BOARDID0', { 
  boundingbox: [-1, 11, 12, -11], axis:true, 
  defaultAxes: {
    x: {
       withLabel: true, 
       name: 't in s',
           label: {
             position: 'rt', 
             offset: [-0, 15], 
             anchorX: 'right'
           },
           ticks: {
             insertTicks: false,
             ticksDistance: 5, 
             minorTicks: 4
           } 
        },
    y: {withLabel:true, name: 'x in m',      
        label: {position: 'rt', offset: [+15, -0]} } },
  showCopyright: false, showNavigation: false 
});
```

Additionally, I set `minorTicks:4`. See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/sxpm1z35/2/

Comment: Now, I can make the axes look exactly like I want them to. – Thanks a lot!